# How to post images in facebook in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

could anyone pls help me to post fotos on facebook using objective c for iphone app.i tried it but its getting terminated  when i check with iphone.its working properly in simulator.following is my code i used to post in fb.i use graph api for developing my app.

```
-(void)fbGraphCallback:(id)sender {

    if ((fbGraph.accessToken == nil) || ([fbGraph.accessToken length] == 0)) {

        NSLog(@"You pressed the 'cancel' or 'Dont Allow' button, you are NOT logged into Facebook...I require you to be logged in & approve access before you can do anything useful....");
        //restart the authentication process.....
        [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self
                                        andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:)
                             andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];
        [self.view addSubview:viewshare];
    } 
    else {  
        NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

        //imgPicture is my image view name
        NSLog(@"the Data::%@\n",imgPicture.image);

        FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:imgPicture.image];

        [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

        [variables setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", txtComment.text] forKey:@"message"];

        FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
        NSLog(@"postPictureButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

        NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile & photo albums...");

        txtComment.text=@" ";
        [txtComment setHidden:YES];
        [lblcmt setHidden:YES];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Successfully posted...Now log into Facebook & look at your profile" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }
    [fbGraph release];
}
```

Comment: Did you run your app through instruments in XCode?

Answer (score 1):

First I check if facebook(the facebook object) has a valid session:

```
if (![facebook_ isSessionValid]) {

   permissions_ = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];
   [facebook_ authorize:permissions_];

}
```

When I can guaranty that i'm logged into facebook I post the image like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   image, @"picture",
                                   message, @"message",
                                   nil];

[facebook_ requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Finally I check this methods in for being sure if the image post was succesful or not:

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    //Error

}

-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    //Succes
}
```